# Replacing a string in HTML element with another string

Tags: javascript

Is there some way to replace a specific string within a HTML element with another string?  I tried using `.replace()` but there was no effect (and no error message in the console either).  See code below.

```
month = 1
date = document.getElementById('date');
date.innerHTML = month + ' months';

if (month == 1) {
    date.innerHTML.replace('months', 'month');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The replace method actually doesn't change the content of the string, it generates a new string with the desired changes, so you should assign it to some variable, or use it as some function parameter.

So in your case, you're just missing reassign it to the `date.innerHTML` like:

```
date.innerHTML = date.innerHTML.replace('months', 'month')
```

Comment: Thanks.  Rookie mistake.  I marked your answer since you provided an explanation.

Comment: We all commit those, no worries, thanks for marking me.

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
month = 1
date = document.getElementById('date');
date.innerHTML = month + ' months';

if (month == 1) {
    date.innerHTML = date.innerHTML.replace('months', 'month');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace to

```
date.innerHTML =  date.innerHTML.replace('months', 'month');
```